# Importing FAQ Documents from SharePoint to QnA Maker not working

Tags: sharepoint, azure-qna-maker

has anyone been able to successfully import FAQ documents from SharePoint into QnAMaker yet?

I've gone through the documentation here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/add-sharepoint-datasources), confirmed all permissions, etc. but am still getting the following error when trying to import from a SharePoint URL:

Bad Argument
Unsupported/Invalid URLs: 
"https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/teams/sitename/library/FAQ.docx"

I was able to upload the same exact document manually to QnAMaker so that tells me it's not a problem with the document format and content.

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation, it looks like this error will appear if you don't accept/allow for the authentication prompt to pop up. Once I allowed for the pop up window to appear, I was able to login with my credentials to allow for the document sync from SharePoint.

On a side note, I also noticed that I had to do hard refreshes and re-authenticate after some time for subsequent FAQ imports.